# window.print() Print only Text

Tags: javascript, printing

Hi i'm making a web based POS and when printing the ticket I use javascript

```
window.print()
```

But I have buttons for going back to the main page, ando I dont want those printed on the ticket, Can I print only Text from a Browser Window? If so how can I do it?

Also Im new at this, so if there's a better way to do this I will appreciate commments about how to do it

tx in advance

Comment: Use [`CSS media queries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to define which gets displayed on print.

Answer (score 0):

Add a print stylesheet that hides everything you do not want to be printed:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">
```

In this stylesheet you could e.g. hide all images using `img { display: none; }` or do something more fancy such as replacing colors with black/white etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into building a print stylesheet.

Here is a guide to how you produce a print stylesheet:

http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml

You need a stylesheet like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```